# wpf: custom window drop shadow

Tags: wpf

I'm working on a c# wpf app with a custom window (allowtransparency = true, resize = none, window style = none).

Now I would like to add drop shadow similar to the zune pc software. I read up on this and  the included dropshadoweffect is not covering all angles of my window and it is said to kill performance.

I want to implement it like this: I add a margin to my layout grid which I programmatically remove when maximizing the app.

What is the best way to add a drop shadow which can be applied to a grid, which doesn't kill performance and drops shadow in all directions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Direction of -75, ShadowDepth of 2 and BlurRadius of 27 helped for me.

Best way is to use blend for doing these.

HTH

Comment: Just wanted to point out - the ShadowDepth of 2 makes a surprisingly large difference here, even with such a large blur. You can get a totally centred 'shadow' (more of an outerglow really) by setting ShadowDepth to 0, but there's absolutely no pop to it, wheras even on a large object the ShadowDepth of 2 establishes it firmly as a shadow rather than an outline.

Answer (score 12):

I've tried the solutions posted here but none of them were getting me close to the end result which I wanted (See screenshot below). So I tried out a couple of different things and I am posting my solution here, just in case someone would be interested in achieving something similar. BTW: if you could improve my solution, please do let me know because I find it a bit redundant at the moment.

[image: Window with blue drop shadow effect]

Ok now for the code that drives this effect:

```xml
    <Window ...
        WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent"
        ...>

    <Border>
        <Border.Effect>
            // opacity does not need to be specified but it looks cooler when you do
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" ShadowDepth="0" Opacity="0.8" 
                Color="Blue" />
        </Border.Effect>

        // make sure the value for Grid Margin is the same as DropShadowEffect 
        // BlurRadius
        <Grid Background="White" Margin="20">

            // I tried setting borderthickness and borderbrush to the previous 
            // <Border> element but instead of the border being shown right after  
            // the grid and before the drop shadow, it would show after the drop 
            // shadow making the overall effect very ugly
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
               // now you can specify whatever you want to display in the window
                <Grid>
                    ....
                </Grid>
            </Border>
       </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 6):

`DropShadowEffect` doesn't "kill performance"... it is rendered using hardware acceleration, and rendering a drop shadow on a window is not a big deal for current GPUs. You're probably confusing with `DropShadowBitmapEffect`, which is software rendered. Anyway all `BitmapEffects` were made obsolete in 3.5 SP1 and don't work at all in 4.0, only `Effects` can be used now

Comment: So I use the dropshadoweffect on my grid then? How can I get it to drop shadow in all directions or do I have to apply multiple effects..?

Answer (score 2):

Building off of Princes's code, I wanted to paste a final product.

```
<Window x:Class="RDNScoreboard.Views.InitialWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="InitialWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
    WindowStyle="None"  
AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent"
   BorderThickness="3"  >
<Border>
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="27" Color="Black" Opacity="0.8" ShadowDepth="2" Direction="-75" />
    </Border.Effect>
    <Grid Background="White"  >
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: This does not take window chrome into account, which is terrible in practice.